# SetAttribute not working in WebBrowser Control

Tags: c#, browser, setattribute

I am developing automation windows application in C# using web browser control.
To set the values to the controls, I am using SetAttribute property. 
It works fine for all the controls but the text box which consist watermarking

For example

[image]

The following is my coding

```
   WebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_Content1_dob_txbx").SetAttribute("value", "09/17/1976");
```

While running the application, the textbox holds the value like watermarking

For example

[image]

while clicking the submit button the date getting vanish. How can I set the date in the watermarking text box?

How can I achieve the following output

[image]

*Note:*
In the website the Watermark achieved by ajax WatermarkExtender

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution
I have set the value in **WebBrowser_ProgressChanged** event now its works fine

```
private void automationWebBrowser_ProgressChanged(object sender, WebBrowserProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
        if (automationWebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_Content1_dob_txbx") != null)
            automationWebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_Content1_dob_txbx").SetAttribute("value", "09/17/1976");
}
```